# Search based on foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Laravel 5.*

I have the `Case` Model that has one to one relationship with `Customer` Model as defined below:

```
public function customer
{
   return $this->hasOne(Customer::class, 'id', 'customer');
}
```

In the cases listing (cases.index), it displays the customer name based on relationship `$case->customer->name`.

I am trying to create search and list all the cases based on customer name.

Is there a native way to search based on the relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method. For example:

```
Case::whereHas('customer', function($q) use($name) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that through [`scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes), put this code in your customer model:

```
 public function scopeOfName($query, $name) {
      $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
 }
```

Then you would access it this way:

```
 $case = Case::with(['customer' => function($query) use ($customerName) {
    $query->ofName($customerName);
 }]);
```